# convert multi level Object values to string javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

i have the following Object

```
var myObject = {
    first:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',
        key4:'value4',
    },
    second:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',

    },
    third:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',
        key4:'value4',
        key5:'value5',
    }
}
```

As you can see the values (value1, value2, value3,...) are in single quote but in real this are not string values it can have number value. My target is to convert this values (value1, value2, value3,...) to string using a loop. I already tried `forEach loop` but it does't work. Do you have any idea???

**--EDIT--**

Some of my object again have child like this

```
var myObject = {
    first:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',
        key4:'value4',
    },
    second:{
        child1:{
             key1:'value1',
             key2:'value2',
             key3:'value3',
             key4:'value4',
        },
        child2:{
             key1:'value1',
             key2:'value2',
             key3:'value3',
             key4:'value4',
        }

    },
    third:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',
        key4:'value4',
        key5:'value5',
    }
}
```

And i want to convert them also to string. What changes i should do?

In Angular js i am doing like this

```
angular.forEach(abc, function(value, key){
        angular.forEach(abc[key], function(v, k){
            if(typeof abc[key][k]==='object'){
                angular.forEach(abc[key][k], function(v1, k1) {
                    abc[key][k][k1] = String(abc[key][k][k1]);
                }); 
            }else{
                abc[key][k] = String(abc[key][k]);
            }
      });
  });
```

But in pure Javascript how can i achieve this?

Comment: _"but in real this are not string values"_ What do you mean? What are the values?

Comment: Please show us two things:  1) An example of the actual data you want us to convert.  2) The code you tried.

Comment: numbers which does't have any quote

Comment: What did you try to convert `Number` to `String`?

Comment: `Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.keys(myObject[key]).forEach(function(k) {
    myObject[key][k] = myObject[key][k] + '';
  });
});`

Comment: convert all of this into a json array and force jsonarray object to string.

Comment: @RushiAyyappa Converting to JSON and back is almost always an inefficient solution.

Comment: @4castle but it would be easier when the time of retrieving back the data.

Comment: @Pranav C Balan's Answer is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) methods.

```
// get all object property names and iterate over them
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {
  // get property names of inner object and iterate over them
  Object.keys(myObject[key]).forEach(function(key1) {
    // update the property value with stringified value(using String constructor)
    myObject[key][key1] = String(myObject[key][key1]);
  });
});
```

```js
var myObject = {
  first: {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
    key4: 4,
  },
  second: {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',

  },
  third: {
    key1: 'value1',
    key2: 'value2',
    key3: 'value3',
    key4: 'value4',
    key5: 'value5',
  }
};

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(function(key) {
  Object.keys(myObject[key]).forEach(function(key1) {
    myObject[key][key1] = String(myObject[key][key1]);
  });
});

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Just a side note: for converting only numbers, `toString()` is fine, but it can throw an exception if the value is `null` or `undefined`. In those cases, it would be necessary to use the `String()` constructor.

Comment: @4castle :  yup you are right.... so I just updated the answer.... thanks

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `for..in` loop, `String()` constructor

```js
var myObject = {
    first:{
        key1:1,
        key2:2,
        key3:3,
        key4:4
    },
    second:{
        key1:1,
        key2:2,
        key3:3

    },
    third:{
        key1:1,
        key2:2,
        key3:3,
        key4:4,
        key5:5
    }
}

for (var prop in myObject) {
  for (var key in myObject[prop]) {
    myObject[prop][key] = String(myObject[prop][key])
  }
}
  
console.log(myObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a for var key in object like this.

```js
var myObject = {
    first:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',
        key4:'value4',
    },
    second:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',

    },
    third:{
        key1:'value1',
        key2:'value2',
        key3:'value3',
        key4:'value4',
        key5:'value5',
        key6: 1555
    }
}

for(var key in myObject) {
  for(var anotherkey in myObject[key]) {
    myObject[key][anotherkey] = String(myObject[key][anotherkey])
  }
}

console.log(myObject);
```

May I also suggest using an Array for your objects. This is exactly what arrays are for, an ordered sequence of elements. Don't use a key value pair for this type of structure,.